# Embed image within php string using img class="aligncenter

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I’m setting up a Wordpress front end submission form to post and everything works fine except when I’m inserting the content

Below is how my current php looks

```
$my_post = array();
$my_post['post_title'] = $newid;
$my_post['post_content'] = $id
$my_post['post_author'] = 1;
$my_post['post_status'] = publish;
$my_post['post_category'] = array($a);
// Insert the post into the database
$post_id = wp_insert_post($my_post);
wp_redirect( site_url()."?p=$post_id" ); exit();
```

The ['post_content'] section currently posts just the image link however im trying to incorporate this with the below

```
<img class="aligncenter" alt="" src="http://domain.com/image/image.gif" />
```

The image link is $id

Ive tried setting up the below that works to an extent except for the "aligncenter"

```
$imageurl = "img class=aligncenter src=";
$imageurl1 = "<";
$imageurl2 = ">";

$my_post['post_content'] = $imageurl1.$imageurl.$id.$imageurl2;
```

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $imageurl = "img class='aligncenter' alt='' src='";
 $imageurl1 = "<";
 $imageurl2 = "'>";

 $my_post['post_content'] = $imageurl1.$imageurl.$id.$imageurl2;
```